# SQL Remove part of string from the end of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, truncate

I know the end of every value in a column - let's say it's "Potato".

Is there any way to remove "Potato" from each row?

I know that `CONCAT` adds a string to the value in a column, but how do I remove a string from the end of every value in the column if I know what's there?

e.g.

```
+-----------+
| MyValue   |
+-----------+
| FooPotato |
| BarPotato |
+-----------+
```

should become:

```
+---------+
| MyValue |
+---------+
| Foo     |
| Bar     |
+---------+
```

Comment: replace is not enough ? `(replace(yourcolumn, 'Potato', '') where yourcolumn like '%Potato'` ? It will replace all Potato in your field, but that might be ok ?

Comment: What do you mean by column ? Do you mean the column name ? Do you mean for every field, replace "Potato" in every row ?

Comment: Raphael I'm not sure that where clause is necessary. Will it not just skip the row if 'Potato' is missing ?

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur well replace is a bit "excessive" if you wanna replace just the "end". So it may be a way to restrict. But yes, it's maybe not necessary.

Comment: It helped me! Dont mind all the folks saying nonsense

Answer (score 16):

```
UPDATE someTable SET someColumn = REPLACE(someColumn, 'Potato', '')
WHERE someColumn LIKE '%Potato'
```

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bfc6/1)

Comment: The % should go to the beginning, if I understood the question right.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer You certainly did. I did not.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause all occurances of 'Potato' to be cutted away? Like 'My Potato is like no other Potato' would be 'My  is like no other '

Comment: I edited your demo to show what I mean: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d44733/1/0

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer interesting

Answer (score 7):

read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

You can use the `LEFT` function to get rid of the end of a String. 'Potato' has 6 chars so, this statement reduces the content of all entries in the column by 6 characters.

```
UPDATE table
SET column =
    LEFT(column, LENGTH(column)-6)
WHERE column LIKE '%Potato';
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d45d/1/0)

Comment: You should probably throw a `WHERE` just in case there isn't a `potato`; or just match `WHERE RIGHT(column) = 'potato'`

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Probably, but the OP explicitly stated that EVERY column ends that way. But yeah, I'll add it.